# Convertion of datastage timestamp to salesforce timestamp format in datastage

Tags: type-conversion, timestamp, salesforce, datastage

Select col1 from table/obj where my_timestamp_col=#datastage_parameter_column#

Here I'm trying to fetch col1 records in Salesforce object soql based on the given timestamp..but datastage and salesforce has a different timestamp format...so I'm getting error..can anyone help me to solve?

Datastage Timestamp format..YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
salesforce timestamp format...YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ (what I need)

Comment: Please provide examples of how it look and how you want it to be. Donot expect everyone knows how a salesforce timestamp looks like.

Comment: I want the datastage timestamp to be in this salesforce format  YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which Salesforce timestamp format you require (there are three).  Let's assume you want YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ (which specifies UTC as "Z" rather than a specific time offset).  If your timestamp is already UTC, then it is a simple transformation of the form `TimestampToString(InLink.MyTimestamp, "%yyyy-%mm-%ssT%hh:%nn:%ssZ")`
You can extrapolate this to remove the Z then append the +hh:mm or -hh:mm for your own timezone.

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting invalid format used for string from time type conversion error in transformer stage..

Comment: Check your syntax.  TimestampToString (not TimeToString).  Check that your data really are of data type timestamp (they might be string already, in which case the solution will involve substring and concatenation operators.